# NEXT JS -unpecified error on ecternal calls

Tags: next.js, internet-explorer

i have a next js UI application that runs on IE browser. i see the an application side error issue only on production whenever making an external call to a system on pressing enter. I see that i got 500 response from external system..And the error that i see on the browser console is attached..
Am using await fetch(url,requestObj) to call the external system. Can someone please let me know what the issue ?
[image: application erroe]

[image: actual error on console]